# Is there any way to specify "latest" version for a pod library?

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

According to the [docs](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) you can use the latest version of a pod library by simply omitting its version in the podfile.

Is there any way to use the latest version by specifying something like `+` or `*` or `latest`?

Answer (score 0):

Use '> 0' as the version specifier.  See [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7332#issuecomment-357669079)